# Show MS ACCESS Tables using ComboBox Selection

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Need your help. I'm a student and I am doing a `VB.Net` program for my Accounting class project. Now, I have little knowledge about using `OleDB` so I'm gonna need your help please.

Here are the details:

1. Database is `MS ACCESS 2007`(`OleDB`)
2. Database Tables are `tbl_login`, `tbl_product`, `tbl_transaction`
3. Forms are `Form1`, `Form2` and 1 `Module`
4. `ComboBox` Values are `Users`, `Product`, `Transaction`
5. Language is `VB`

As the I run the program, a Log-in form (`Form 1`) will appear and will require username and password. As the user submits his username and password, the program will check if it matches in the database table named `tbl_login`. If it matches then proceed to next form (`Form 2`). Here, a `ListView` and a `ComboBox` is present. As it loads, The Default content of the listview are the contents of `tbl_login` and combobox value is `Users`.

Now, what I want my program to do is that when I changed the combobox value to `Products`, the listview items will be the contents of `tbl_products` and when combobox value is `transaction`, `tbl_transaction` contents will appear in the `listview`.

How will I code this one?

I would really appreciate all your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the VB.NET version so I'll assume .NET 4.0 runtime. I advise you read about combobox events, the DataSource property of controls. You need to put code in the SelectionChanged event of the combobox to pick up the SelectedValue, query the tbl_transaction table and assign the DatSource property of the ListView. I don't think i should add more as you should work for your homework.

Comment: I got the answer to my question. Thanks Raj for trying to help. I really appreciate it. :) I'll post my code later.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I just experimented on some areas and I don't know what exactly solved the problem. :) First, I changed all data types of my tables' fields from Numbers to Text. Second, I revised some codes in form2_load and combobox_selectedindexchanged.

Before:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source = ..\Accounting2.accdb"
    con.Open()
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    sSqlUser = "SELECT df, sdf, asdf FROM tbl_login ORDER BY df"
    sSqlProduct = "SELECT cv, xcv, zxcv FROM tbl_product ORDER BY cv"
    sSqlTransaction = "SELECT rt, ert, wert, qwert FROM tbl_transaction ORDER BY rt"
    sSql = sSqlUser
    Call FillList()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        sSql = sSqlUser

    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        sSql = sSqlProduct

    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        sSql = sSqlTransaction

    End If
End Sub
```

---

Then:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source = ..\Accounting2.accdb"
    con.Open()

    sSqlUser = "SELECT df, sdf, asdf FROM tbl_login ORDER BY df"
    sSqlProduct = "SELECT cv, xcv, zxcv FROM tbl_product ORDER BY cv"
    sSqlTransaction = "SELECT rt, ert, wert, qwert FROM tbl_transaction ORDER BY rt"
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        sSql = sSqlUser

    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        sSql = sSqlProduct

    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        sSql = sSqlTransaction

    End If
    Call FillList()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
End Sub
```